# ajax problems xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

estoy aprendiendo ajax y al momento de hacer una consulta me sale este error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///C:/Users/tiago/JavascriptModernoUdemy/js/empleado.json' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

**HTML**

```
<p id="mostrar"></p>
<button id="boton">Boton Ajax</button>
```

**JS**

```
const btn = document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", () => {

    //crear el objeto xml
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    //abrir una conexion para txt es get,base de datos es post,actualizando es put, y borrando es delete
    xhr.open("GET", "empleado.json", true)//true porque es asincrono

    //una vez que carga
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            const persona = Json.parse(this.responseText)
            const html = `             
                <ul>
                    <li>${persona.nombre}</li>
                    <li>${persona.apellido}</li>
                </ul>                                         
                `
            document.getElementById("mostrar").innerHTML = html
        }
    }
    //enviar el request
    xhr.send()
});
```

Comment: Prueba utilizando "onreadystatechange" en vez de "onload". Esta ultima es más nueva y por ahí tu navegador no lo soporta. Tambien te recomiendo poner una condicional con (this.readyState == 4) dentro de la que ya tienes.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El mensaje de error indica que estás haciendo una petición a un sito externo al tuyo, y dicha petición es bloqueada por seguridad. Debes configurar la petición para que sea una petición `CORS`. Sugiero que revises [este tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) donde se explica paso a paso como hacerlo, previamente hay que verificar que tu navegador sea compatible con peticiones CORS (allí también dice qué versiones de navegador son compatibles).